# How to put legend outside interactive mode plot in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend, ipywidgets

I created interactive plot in Jupyter Notebook by using Ipywidgets.

```
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets

drop_down1=widgets.Dropdown(
options=data.columns.values,
value='Age',
description='First Column:',
disabled=False,
 )

drop_down2=widgets.Dropdown(
options=data.columns.values,
value='Gender',
description='Second Column:',
disabled=False,
 )

def update_barchart(column1, column2):
return data.groupby([column1, 
column2]).size().unstack().plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)

interactive(update_barchart, column1=drop_down1,column2=drop_down2)
```

It creates bar plot. But the problem is that it shows the legend inside the plot. 
pyplot.legend method is tried to handle legend but is not working in ipywidgets/interactive plot.

How a legend can be put outside plot in interactive mode in jupyter notebook??

Comment: *"But in interactive plot, I am not using this technique."* - This just tells you that you should use that technique, even in interactive plots.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest I tried "pyplot.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))", but it shows "No handles with labels found to put in legend."

Comment: Ok, so your question has nothing to do with interactive plots, but rather how to put the legend of a stacked pandas plot outside the axes, right?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest. NO. I can put legend outside the plot when I do not use interactive plot. But the same technique is not working in interactive plot.

Comment: In that case I do not understand the problem. It would be helpful though if you showed the code that does not work. Also see [mcve].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest. I used pyplot.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))  before 
interactive(update_barchart, column1=drop_down1,column2=drop_down2), but it does not work and legend still shows inside plot area. When I write the code after interactive() section, it shows "No handles with labels found to put in legend".

Comment: You need to first create the plot, then the legend.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest It is not working in ipywidgets interactive mode. I created the plot first, when I try to create legend after creating plot, it shows "matplotlib.legend:No handles with labels found to put in legend" and does not show plot.

Comment: You are not helping me in understanding the problem. If you do not show the code that works in static mode and the code you tried in interactive mode, I cannot help further.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest The static mode code: data.groupby(['Gender','Age']).size().unstack().plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))   It shows the legend outside of the plot area.

Comment: Yes, this works because you create the legend after the plot. You need to do the same with your interactive plot.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest and for the interactive mode, the code is in this post, at the beginning of the post.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest Yes I put the code  "plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))" after interactive(update_barchart, column1=drop_down1,column2=drop_down2) in interactive mode, it shows  "No handles with labels found to put in legend"

Comment: If you put it after `interactive...` it will not apply to your plot, but to a new empty plot. You need to put it into the updating function

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest found solution now. Actually "return" needs to be removed, then pyplot.legend will execute! Never thought it before!!